# how to send live audio (not file!) byte array data to browser

Tags: java, media, audio-streaming, spring-restcontroller

a continuous data is added to the **audioService**. I see it sent like this but no sound is playing. [f12 dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aneQG.png).

```
@GetMapping(value = "/audio/live/{id}")
public StreamingResponseBody liveAudio(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {

            try {

                try {
                    byte[] audioBytes = audioService.getAudio(id);
                    out.write(MyAudioUtil.convertWav(audioBytes).toByteArray());
                    out.flush();
                } catch (InterruptedException | CloseNowException | ClientAbortException exc) {
                    //ignore these exceptions
                    return;
                }

                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("blabblablab", e);
                return;
            }

        }
        //}
    };
}
```

Comment: I want the audio data I sent to play, I have no problem when I save the data to the file.

Comment: maybe i can solve the problem if i can add header information to StreamingResponseBody (ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .header("Content-Type", "audio/wav")) etc..

Answer (score 0):

Add Jlayer to your dependency.
on gradle

```
    implementation group: 'javazoom', name: 'jlayer', version: '1.0.1'
```

on maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javazoom</groupId>
  <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding jlayer, read your input and play with jlayer

```
BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(audioBytes.toByteArray()));
    Player player = new Player(inputStream); //player from jplayer
    player.play();
```

Comment: are you sure this will work in the browser?

Comment: give it a shot @erkant